# Replace one fragment to another

Tags: android, fragment

I have an `Activity` and opening a `Fragment A` inside it in `RelativeLayout`. After that when I click to open `Fragment B` inside same `RelativeLayout` it gives following error

```
" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0d00cf (com.healthiera.mobile:id/Content_id_) for fragment CompAndSymp{21e51fb8 #1 id=0x7f0d00cf}
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1102)"
```

I think the problem is that I am trying to open `Fragment B` in `Activity` when I am in `Fragment A`(not in activity). I don't know how to solve my problem other way. Please suggest me what to do.

I found many others having same problem, but I couldn't find solution.

Here is my code when I'm trying to open `Fragment B inside Fragment A`. Dashboard is my `Fragment B`.

```
  Dashboard dashboard = new Dashboard();
                      getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.Content_id_, dashboard).commit();
```

Activity XML

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/Content_id_">
    </RelativeLayout>

    <com.aurelhubert.ahbottomnavigation.AHBottomNavigation
        android:id="@+id/AHBottomNavigation_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Show your xml and how you call the fragments so we can help you faster.

Comment: I just edit my question. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, I solve, here is the solution

Comment: Dashboard dashboard = new Dashboard(); getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, dashboard).commit();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution.
For replacing fragment to another fragment

Dashboard dashboard = new Dashboard();                    getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, dashboard).commit();

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem using interfaces.

You can create an interface extending the main activity.

```
public interface MyInterface(){
  void goToFragmentB();
}
```

now, in your mainActivity you implement this interface and you set up the void method required way to replace fragment A with fragment B.

In your fragment you can retrive the activity. Now simply cast this activity to MyInterface:

```
MyInterface myInterface = (MyInterface) myActivityRetrieved;
```

And onButtonClick you can call

```
myInterface.goToFragmentB();
```

And you are done.

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Do:

```
     getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(Fragmnet B)
```

Don't :Add same fragment over other with illegal context as before .ALSO paste your code and exception at line if above code doesn't work so that we can have better insight.

EDIT:Concept building:

Well i can just paste code and can help you reslove the crash   but the problem you are facing is a basic android concept that is must to know having said many other misses this:

First try using

```
 <FrameLayout 
    android:height="match_parent"
    android:width"match_parent"/>
```

instead of Relative layout

Now When activity holds a fragment there should be  a way to communicate between activity and fragments it is holding 
Since Fragment has its own life cycle which solely depends on activity's life-cycle.  you need to handle fragment's own life cycle in order to save data and restore its views

In your case you need to communicate From Fragment A to fragment B via parent activity so activity needs a callback to change to other fragment via frament manager
following are few links which can help:take time to read this

[link one](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html)

[link two](https://gist.github.com/StevenByle/5729698)

[link 3](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)

[link four](http://www.truiton.com/2015/12/android-activity-fragment-communication/)
Happy Coding :)

Comment: see my edited answer ..!! It will help for sure You are missing some basic android concepts

Comment: Thank you so much for understanding me. I'll read your links and hope after that will solve my problem.

Comment: You can up-vote and accept my answer if it helped . In-case you face any problem while implementing feel free to add comment here

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
Dashboard dashboard = new Dashboard();
getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.Content_id_, dashboard).commit();
```

Hope that helps.